# Need a scala functional code for validating ipv4 and ipv6

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I was trying to construct functional program for parsing IP address. I am seeing an error. I wanted a simpler code which differentiates ipv4 to ipv6. Here is the JAVA code.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
class Solution {
  String chunkIPv4 = "([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])";
  Pattern pattenIPv4 =
          Pattern.compile("^(" + chunkIPv4 + "\\.){3}" + chunkIPv4 + "$");

  String chunkIPv6 = "([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})";
  Pattern pattenIPv6 =
          Pattern.compile("^(" + chunkIPv6 + "\\:){7}" + chunkIPv6 + "$");

  public String validIPAddress(String IP) {
    if (pattenIPv4.matcher(IP).matches()) return "IPv4";
    return (pattenIPv6.matcher(IP).matches()) ? "IPv6" : "Neither";
  }
}
```

Comment: And what is the error you're seeing?

Comment: That is **Java**, not **Scala**.

Comment: @stefanobaghino I updated the code to rule on scala.   It is failing the test case for "172.16.254.1".     Code: var chunkIPv4: String = "([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"
var pattenIPv4: Pattern =
    Pattern.compile("^(" + chunkIPv4 + "\\.){3}" + chunkIPv4 + "$")
  var chunkIPv6: String = "([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})"

  var pattenIPv6: Pattern =
    Pattern.compile("^(" + chunkIPv6 + "\\:){7}" + chunkIPv6 + "$")
  def validIPAddress(IP: String): String = {
    if (pattenIPv4.matcher(IP).matches()) "IPv4"
    if ((pattenIPv6.matcher(IP).matches())) "IPv6" else "Neither" }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your scala solution that you wrote in the comment has the following:

```
  def validIPAddress(IP: String): String = {
    if (pattenIPv4.matcher(IP).matches()) "IPv4"
    if (pattenIPv6.matcher(IP).matches()) "IPv6"
    else "Neither"
  }
```

The first `if` line will be evaluated but will not return without a `return` keyword, so it will fall through the next conditional.
You can fix that in two ways, one is to add `return`:

`if (pattenIPv4.matcher(IP).matches()) return "IPv4"`

or maybe better add an `else` to the second line, so you can avoid the `return` as the whole thing will be evaluated as a single expression:

```
  def validIPAddress(IP: String): String = {
    if (pattenIPv4.matcher(IP).matches()) "IPv4"
    else if (pattenIPv6.matcher(IP).matches()) "IPv6"
    else "Neither"
  }
```

Also, as a side note, all those `var`s can be `val`s since you are not mutating them, and it's a good practice in scala to have the guarantee that they will always have the same value.